# Fail to display gcc version

Tags: gcc

I have successfully installed gcc on my AIX machine.
But, gcc --version does not display the version

```
# rpm -ivh gcc-8-1.aix7.1.ppc.rpm
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        package gcc-1:8-1.ppc is already installed
# gcc --version
ksh: gcc:  not found.
```

Could you point me out if something has gone wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Does ksh need the equivalent of `rehash` to find binaries newly added to PATH directories?

Comment: You might need to add `/opt/freeware/bin` into your `PATH`.